# Create hypothesis strategy that returns unique values

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

I'm trying to create a `hypothesis` strategy which produces integers with no repeats.  Here's my code:

```py
import hypothesis
import hypothesis.strategies as strategies

def unique(strat):
    previous = set()

    @strategies.composite
    def new_strategy(draw):
        while True:
            value = draw(strat)
            if value not in previous:
                previous.add(value)
                return value

    return new_strategy

strategy = unique(strategies.integers(min_value=0, max_value=1000))

@hypothesis.given(num=strategy)
def test_unique(num):
    pass
```

However, when I run `pytest`, I get

```
    @check_function
    def check_strategy(arg, name="")
        if not isinstance(arg, SearchStrategy):
            hint = ""
            if isinstance(arg, (list, tuple)):
                hint = ", such as st.sampled_from({}),".format(name or "...")
            if name:
                name += "="
            raise InvalidArgument(
                "Expected a SearchStrategy%s but got %s%r (type=%s)"
                % (hint, name, arg, type(arg).__name__)
            )
E           hypothesis.errors.InvalidArgument: Expected a SearchStrategy but got mapping['num']=<function accept.<locals>.new_strategy at 0x7f30622418b0> (type=function)
```

Comment: Also, how would your strategy handle strats with a finite set of values, such as `hypothesis.strategies.booleans()` or `hypothesis.strategies.integers(0, 5)`?

Comment: @NicholasM, I admit I've thought of this but don't have an answer yet.  For my use case, I'll just make sure to not make the sample size too large.

Answer (score 1):

```
@st.composite
def unique(draw, strategy):
    seen = draw(st.shared(st.builds(set), key="key-for-unique-elems"))
    return draw(
        strategy
        .filter(lambda x: x not in seen)
        .map(lambda x: seen.add(x) or x)
    )
```

There's a couple of cute tricks here:

1. Use `st.shared()` to create a new `seen` cache for each distinct example.  This fixes your "what if you run out of values" problem, but *also* fixes your critical "the test can't replay failures" problem which would make the whole thing horribly flaky.

   - For advanced tricks, try using the `key=` argument to `shared`, or having it construct a dictionary.
2. `.filter(...)` to exclude already-seen items.  This is better than a loop because it means Hypothesis can more effectively avoid and report on futile attempts to generate a not-yet-seen example.
3. The `.map(...)` call to add it to the set is a blatant abuse of the facts that `set.add()` returns `None` after mutating the object, and that `or` evaluates to the second item if the first is falsey.

Comment: Oops, yep - the `st.sets()` strategy needs an `elements=` argument, so I switched to `st.builds(set)` instead of `st.sets(st.nothing())` - the latter would work but it's a bit obscure for my taste, and adding `max_size=0` would be overly verbose.

Comment: Still getting repeat values.

Comment: Aaand, if we pass the `key=` argument to `shared()` it actually works.

Comment: Still getting repeat values.

Comment: Repeats in different calls to your test function are meant to be possible (and required during shrinking, replay, and flake-detection); if within an example post your output?

Comment: 0, 0, 960, 0, 744, 0, 817, ...